# How to set the arraylist values to listview in android?

Tags: android

I need to display my arraylist data in listview. My arraylist is of type              `public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ourstringList1`. In **my listadapter class I am trying to get the data from arraylist and setting it to tesxtview. But since I need arr.get(i).get(j)..**.I am unable to proceed further.
Please help me regarding this...

My code:
public class testreview extends Activity {

```
private ListView listViewScore = null;
private ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = null;
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ourstringList1 = Select.stringList1;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> usernameArrLst = ourstringList1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    listViewScore=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    usernameArrLst = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter();
    listViewScore.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
}

class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(usernameArrLst==null){
            return 0;
        }

        return usernameArrLst.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return usernameArrLst.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rowView=view;
        if(rowView==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutinflate =LayoutInflater.from(testreview.this);
            rowView=layoutinflate.inflate(R.layout.listrow, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textViewName=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_case);
        textViewName.setText((CharSequence) usernameArrLst.get(position));

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Describe how you want the data displayed in your list view, as you essentially have a grid of data, you could display all the values in one list, have each ArrayList under a separate header/section of the list etc...

Comment: Hi i am wroking on quiz application. In my arraylist data is stored as  row and column. So i need to get 1st row 1st column and then i have to set that to textview in listview. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose i think you need to write your custom adapter and set to the list
 [Get The Idea](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ourstringList1);  i have given like this but it is not taking 3 arguments...

Answer (score 0):

sweety if u have showed us what you have tried then it should have been better.But as per my understanding ur code should look like this   :

```
public class TestProjeectActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listViewScore = null;
    private ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = null;
    private String[] usernameArr = null;

        private ArrayList<String> usernameArrLst = null;

    //private Helper helper = null;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listViewScore=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewScore);

        //helper = new Helper(TestProjeectActivity.this);
        //usernameArr = helper.getUserName();


        usernameArr = new String[]{"Alan","Bob"};

        usernameArrLst = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(usernameArr));//Changed line 


        listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter();
        listViewScore.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    }

    class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(usernameArrLst==null){
                return 0;
            }

            return usernameArr.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return usernameArrLst.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View rowView=view;

            if(rowView==null){
                LayoutInflater layoutinflate =LayoutInflater.from(TestProjeectActivity.this);
                rowView=layoutinflate.inflate(R.layout.listviewtext, parent, false);
            }

            TextView textViewName=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);



            textViewName.setText(usernameArr.get(position));

            return rowView;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response..I am getting error near  listViewScore.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);...can you please tell me why it is showing exception near that line..do we need to create setadapter class?

Comment: @Sweety can u just let me know what is the exception.... and no we dont have to create setAdapter class

Comment: Hi I have kept my code..please check once where am I going wrong?

Comment: @sweety your arraylist is null ...please pass a value to arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, did not see you had imbricated ArrayList. To get the elements you need, use class casting to get to the inner ArrayList and iterate trough them.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList;

stringList = ourStringList1;

for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<String> innerStringList = (ArrayList<String>) stringList.get(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < innerStringList.size(); j++) {
        String value = (String) innerStringList.get(j);

        // put the value in the textView
    }
}
```

When you build your Adapter class, create a class attribute that will hold the array of ArrayList and initialize it in the constructor.

Hope this helps. If you need further explanation let me know.